# Mission : Create a connection with a list of videos and a canvas make them plays 1 by 1, without stops, no click function, ended AddEventListener

Tags: html, video, canvas, playlist

I would like to make a video playlist, (Source video is copied in a canvas to block controls, 
options like download video), i made 2 Drag and Drop lists and i would like to connect 1 drag n Drop list to the canvas (that is also the video player box) then play the videos 1 by 1, 
witout stops, no click function, function AddEventListener ended in the canvas box.

I worth for 2 videos, here is some parts of the code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // listener function changes src
    function myNewSrc() {
        var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        myVideo.src = "videos/80s_Mix_II-700.mp4";
        myVideo.src = "videos/80s_Mix_II-700.webm";
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();
    }



    // add a listener function to the ended event
    function myAddListener() {
        var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
    }

</script>



<body onload="myAddListener()">

    <div id="video_player_box">

        <video id="video" autoplay autobuffer width="1" height="1" >
            <source src="videos/milenio_6_minimix_700.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="videos/milenio_6_minimix_700.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="videos/milenio_6_minimix_700.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        </video>

        <div align="center">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1130" height="560">
                Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
        </div>



        <script>

            var v = document.getElementById("video");
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            ctx = c.getContext('2d');

            v.addEventListener('play', function() {
                var i = window.setInterval(function()
                {
                    ctx.drawImage(v, 5, 5, 1130, 560)
                }, 20);
            }, false);
            v.addEventListener('pause', function() {
                window.clearInterval(i);
            }, false);
            v.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                clearInterval(i);
            }, false);

        </script>

    </div> 


    <div id="cadre2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> <p> Canal VIP </p>
        <ol><li> <video src="videos/milenio_6_minimix_700.mp4" draggable="true"   
                        ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="288" height="188" alt="Video 1">
                </video></li>
```

...

The idea is to say get the videos from #cadre2, play them, 1 by 1, in the canvas until the end and loop, make the same path.

I made my list Drag and drop to have the decision to modify online the video playlist, more flexible.

Hope to have some advises!! I'm not pro of Php and dynamic, i've started Javascript but 
it takes time to be pro!

If you have some code, it will be really appreciated!! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a player that can play videos continously you need to implement some sort of double-buffering at load level (I'll demonstrate later).

But there are some issues in the code as it is -

```
myVideo.src = "videos/80s_Mix_II-700.mp4";
myVideo.src = "videos/80s_Mix_II-700.webm";
myVideo.load();
```

This will simply override the source property. And setting the source will automatically start loading the video.

The proper way to check for video support is using the method `canPlayType` like this:

```
/// which format can we play?
if (video.canPlayType("video/mp4").length > 0) {
    video.src = urlToMP4;

} else if (video.canPlayType("video/webm").length > 0) {
    video.src = urlToWEBM;

} else {
    video.src = urlToOggOrSomeOtherSupportedFormat;
}
```

The problem though with `canPlayType` is that it returns `maybe` in Chrome and `probably` in Firefox. It returns an empty string if it cannot play the video type so we check if string contains anything to determine the possibility for this format to play.

You also need to implement an event listener for `canplay` which tells your app that the video was loaded and buffered successfully and can now be started using play (or starts if `autoplay` was set to `true`).

I would recommend a simple procedure like this:

- Create an array of objects with the video URLs you want to play for the various formats
- When first video is loaded (`canplay`) start loading the next video in the list when start playing the first

I would also recommend a re-factoring of the code to handle loading and playing.

For example, if we initialize an array to hold our custom video objects:

```
var list = [];
```

we can now add URLs like this:

```
function addVideo(urlMP4, url) {
    list.push({
        urlMP4: urlMP4,
        url: url,
        isReady: false
    })
}
```

Then this function will let us add a MP4 and a link for WEBM or OGG:

```
addVideo('http://video1.mp4', 'http://video1.webm');
addVideo('http://video2.mp4', 'http://video2.webm');
addVideo('http://video3.mp4', 'http://video3.ogg');
...
```

Then we need to start a "chain-reaction" so to speak by using a double-buffered loading mechanism. The first time we need to trigger it manually:

```
getVideo(list[0], play);

function getVideo(vid, callback) {

    /// which video is playing? (see demo for details)
    var video = (isVideo1 === false ? video1 : video2),
        me = this;

    /// we need to know when video is ready
    video.addEventListener('canplay', canPlay, false);;

    /// call this when ready
    function canPlay(e) {

        /// remove event listener (in case setting new src does not trigger)
        video.removeEventListener('canplay', canPlay, false);

        /// update our object with useful data, for example:
        vid.isReady = true;

        /// if we provided a callback then call that with custom video object
        if (typeof callback === 'function')
            callback(vid);
    }

    /// check video format support (see demo for details)
    if (video.canPlayType("video/mp4").length > 0) {
        video.src = vid.urlMP4;

    } else {
        video.src = vid.url;
    }
}
```

Our `play` function will manage which video is playing and what to play next:

```
function play(){

    /// what video is currently not playing?
    var video = (isVideo1 === false ? video1 : video2),
        next = current; /// current is index for list, starts at 0

    /// switch
    isVideo1 = !isVideo1;

    /// increment for next video to platy and start over if list ended    
    next++;
    if (next > list.length - 1) next = 0;

    /// only attempt next if there are more videos than 1 in list
    if (list.length > 0) getVideo(list[next]);

    /// start already loaded video (getVideo)
    video.play();
    isPlaying = true;

    /// set current to next in list
    current = next;
}
```

**[Here is an online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/a8g4n/)**

I made this demo just to demonstrate the double-buffered loading. Feel free to incorporate in your own project with pause, stop etc.

There is room to move things around in the code I provided here but it's as said just example of the principle. You also need to consider a scenario where next video takes longer to load then what current video playing takes to play (ie. current video ends before next has finished loading). This is not checked in this code.

In order to properly synchronize video frames with canvas you **need** to use `requestAnimationFrame` or you will get freezes from time to time.

In the demo the loop runs all the time. You can consider to implement a conditional to stop the loop. I just implemented a conditional for drawing when video list has started playing (rAF does not use much resources in it self and you may get problems synchronizing stop and start when you switch videos so I would personally leave it running as-is for this type of scenarios (continuous video play) and only stop it if there is an error occurring).

Comment: Thanks so much Ken!!! That's really appreciated!! I'll check it out your website. It's so better then changing the src, if i want to link it with my drag and drop list box in the same page, what should i do, 
Say : Grab videos from #cadre2 <ol>, probably i will do it in an other web page for the video selection of the person. But i have a dougt, if the list is a Drag and Drop box, how could it stays in the drop box without losing the drop files when the browser refresh ? 
Sorry to ask many questions, i'm beginner with these languages. 
Thanks for everything!!!